# Issue with Vite import (dynamic component?)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vite, i18next

its my first time using vite and my banner.ts and all of the other "component" in the commands folder isn't updating like i wanted even the console log show only on loading the page and when i call again the banner nothing happen (it still appear on the website made cli like it need to do but the language isn't changing)

src/commands/banner.ts

```
import command from '../../config.json' assert {type: 'json'};
import {t} from "../i18n"
import i18n from "i18next";



const createBanner = () : string[] => {
  const banner : string[] = [];
  banner.push("<br>")
  command.ascii.forEach((ele) => {
    let bannerString = "";
    //this is for the ascii art
    for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
      if (ele[i] === " ") {
        bannerString += "&nbsp;";
      } else {
        bannerString += ele[i];
      }
    }

    let eleToPush = `<pre>${bannerString}</pre>`;
    banner.push(eleToPush);
  });
  console.log("test ?")
  banner.push("<br>");
  banner.push(t("bannergreetings").toString());
  console.log("Current Language: ", i18n.language);
  banner.push("Type <span class='command'>'help'</span> for a list of all available commands.");
  banner.push(`Type <span class='command'>'repo'</span> to view the GitHub repository or click <a href='${command.repoLink}' target='_blank'>here</a>.`);
  banner.push("<br>");
  return banner;
}

export const BANNER = createBanner();
```

src/commands/help.ts

```
import {t} from "../i18n"
const helpObj = {
  "commands": [
    [
      t("languagecommand").toString(),
      t("languagecommanddesc").toString(),
    ],
    [
    "'about'",
    "Who made this website?",
    ],
    [
      "'projects'",
      "Maybe there's something interesting."
    ],
    [
      "'whoami'",
      "A perplexing question."
    ],
    ["'sudo'",
      "???"
    ],
    [
      "'repo'",
      "View the Github Repository."
    ],
    ["'banner'",
      "Display the banner."
    ],
    [
      "'clear'",
      "Clear the terminal."
    ],
    [
      "'credit'",
      "See all the credit of this website."
    ]
  ],
}

const createHelp = () : string[] => {
  const help : string[] = []
  help.push("<br>")

  helpObj.commands.forEach((ele) => {
    const SPACE = "&nbsp;";
    let string = "";
    string += SPACE.repeat(2);
    string += "<span class='command'>";
    string += ele[0];
    string += "</span>";
    string += SPACE.repeat(17 - ele[0].length);
    string += ele[1];
    help.push(string);
  })

  help.push("<br>");
  help.push("Press <span class='keys'>[Tab]</span> for auto-completion.");
  help.push("Press <span class='keys'>[Esc]</span> to clear the input line.");
  help.push("Press <span class='keys'>[↑][↓]</span> to scroll through your history of commands.");
  help.push("<br>");
  return help
}

export const HELP = createHelp();
```

src/i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import frTranslation from './language/fr.json';
import enTranslation from './language/en.json';

i18n
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources: {
            fr: { translation: frTranslation },
            en: { translation: enTranslation }
        },
        lng: 'en',
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        // Vous pouvez effectuer des actions supplémentaires ici si nécessaire
        console.log('i18next initialized successfully');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error initializing i18next:', error);
    });

export const t = (key, options) => i18n.t(key, options);
export default i18n;
```

src/main.ts

```
import command from '../config.json' assert {type: 'json'};
import { HELP } from "./commands/help";
import { BANNER } from "./commands/banner";
import { ABOUT } from "./commands/about"
import { DEFAULT } from "./commands/default";
import { PROJECTS } from "./commands/projects";
import { createWhoami } from "./commands/whoami";
import {t} from "./i18n"
import i18n, {changeLanguage} from "i18next";

//mutWriteLines gets deleted and reassigned
let mutWriteLines = document.getElementById("write-lines");
let historyIdx = 0
let tempInput = ""
let userInput : string;
let isSudo = false;
let isPasswordInput = false;
let passwordCounter = 0;
let bareMode = false;

//WRITELINESCOPY is used to during the "clear" command
const WRITELINESCOPY = mutWriteLines;
const TERMINAL = document.getElementById("terminal");
const USERINPUT = document.getElementById("user-input") as HTMLInputElement;
const INPUT_HIDDEN = document.getElementById("input-hidden");
const PASSWORD = document.getElementById("password-input");
const PASSWORD_INPUT = document.getElementById("password-field") as HTMLInputElement;
const PRE_HOST = document.getElementById("pre-host");
const PRE_USER = document.getElementById("pre-user");
const HOST = document.getElementById("host");
const USER = document.getElementById("user");
const PROMPT = document.getElementById("prompt");
const COMMANDS = ["help", "about", "projects", "whoami", "repo", "banner", "clear"];
const HISTORY : string[] = [];
const SUDO_PASSWORD = command.password;
const REPO_LINK = command.repoLink;

const scrollToBottom = () => {
  const MAIN = document.getElementById("main");
  if(!MAIN) return

  MAIN.scrollTop = MAIN.scrollHeight;
}

function userInputHandler(e : KeyboardEvent) {
  const key = e.key;

  switch(key) {
    case "Enter":
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!isPasswordInput) {
        enterKey();
      } else {
        passwordHandler();
      }

      scrollToBottom();
      break;
    case "Escape":
      USERINPUT.value = "";
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      arrowKeys(key);
      e.preventDefault();
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      arrowKeys(key);
      break;
    case "Tab":
      tabKey();
      e.preventDefault();
      break;
  }
}

function enterKey() {
  if (!mutWriteLines || !PROMPT) return
  const resetInput = "";
  let newUserInput;
  userInput = USERINPUT.value;

  if (bareMode) {
    newUserInput = userInput;
  } else {
    newUserInput = `<span class='output'>${userInput}</span>`;
  }

  HISTORY.push(userInput);
  historyIdx = HISTORY.length

  //if clear then early return
  if (userInput === 'clear') {
    commandHandler(userInput.toLowerCase().trim());
    USERINPUT.value = resetInput;
    userInput = resetInput;
    return
  }

  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = `<span id="prompt">${PROMPT.innerHTML}</span> ${newUserInput}`;

  if (mutWriteLines.parentNode) {
    mutWriteLines.parentNode.insertBefore(div, mutWriteLines);
  }

  /*
  if input is empty or a collection of spaces, 
  just insert a prompt before #write-lines
  */
  if (userInput.trim().length !== 0) {
      commandHandler(userInput.toLowerCase().trim());
    }
  
  USERINPUT.value = resetInput;
  userInput = resetInput; 
}

function tabKey() {
  let currInput = USERINPUT.value;

  for (const ele of COMMANDS) {
    if(ele.startsWith(currInput)) {
      USERINPUT.value = ele;
      return
    }
  }
}

function arrowKeys(e : string) {
  switch(e){
    case "ArrowDown":      
      if (historyIdx !== HISTORY.length) {
          historyIdx += 1;
          USERINPUT.value = HISTORY[historyIdx];
          if (historyIdx === HISTORY.length) USERINPUT.value = tempInput;  
      }      
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      if (historyIdx === HISTORY.length) tempInput = USERINPUT.value;
      if (historyIdx !== 0) {
        historyIdx -= 1;
        USERINPUT.value = HISTORY[historyIdx];
      }
      break;
  }
}

function commandHandler(input : string) {

  const parts = input.split(' ');
  const command = parts[0];
  const params = parts.slice(1);


  if(input.startsWith("rm -rf") && input.trim() !== "rm -rf") {
    if (isSudo) {
      if(input === "rm -rf src" && !bareMode) {
        bareMode = true;

        setTimeout(() => {
          if(!TERMINAL || !WRITELINESCOPY) return
          TERMINAL.innerHTML = "";
          TERMINAL.appendChild(WRITELINESCOPY);
          mutWriteLines = WRITELINESCOPY;
        });

        easterEggStyles();
        setTimeout(() => {
          writeLines(["What made you think that was a good idea?", "<br>"]);
        }, 200)

        setTimeout(() => {
          writeLines(["Now everything is ruined.", "<br>"]);
        }, 1200)

        } else if (input === "rm -rf src" && bareMode) {
          writeLines(["there's no more src folder.", "<br>"])
        } else {
          if(bareMode) {
            writeLines(["What else are you trying to delete?", "<br>"])
          } else {
            writeLines(["<br>", "Directory not found.", "type <span class='command'>'ls'</span> for a list of directories.", "<br>"]);
          }
        } 
      } else {
        writeLines(["Permission not granted.", "<br>"]);
    }
    return
  }

  switch(command) {
    case 'clear':
      setTimeout(() => {
        if(!TERMINAL || !WRITELINESCOPY) return
        TERMINAL.innerHTML = "";
        TERMINAL.appendChild(WRITELINESCOPY);
        mutWriteLines = WRITELINESCOPY;
      })
      break;
    case 'banner':
      if(bareMode) {
        writeLines([t("bannergreetings").toString(), "<br>"])
        break;
      }
      writeLines(BANNER);
      break;
    case 'help':
      if(bareMode) {
        writeLines(["maybe restarting your browser will fix this.", "<br>"])
        break;
      }
      writeLines(HELP);
      break;
    case 'language':
      if (bareMode) {
        writeLines([t('message').toString(), "<br>"]);
        break;
      }
      // Vérifiez si des arguments de langue sont fournis
      if (params.length > 0) {
        const newLanguage = params[0].toLowerCase();

        // Vérifiez si la langue est déjà celle actuelle
        if (newLanguage === i18n.language) {
          writeLines([`Language is already set to ${newLanguage.toUpperCase()}`, "<br>"]);
        } else {
          // Vérifiez si la langue existe dans les langues disponibles
          const availableLanguages = Object.keys(i18n.services.resourceStore.data);
          if (availableLanguages.includes(newLanguage)) {
            // Utilisez la commande changeLanguage pour changer la langue
            changeLanguage(newLanguage);
            setTimeout(() => {
              if(!TERMINAL || !WRITELINESCOPY) return
              TERMINAL.innerHTML = "";
              TERMINAL.appendChild(WRITELINESCOPY);
              mutWriteLines = WRITELINESCOPY;
            })
            writeLines(BANNER)
            writeLines([t("changedlanguage").toString(), "<br>"]);
            console.log("Current Language: ", i18n.language);
          } else {
            writeLines([`Language ${newLanguage.toUpperCase()} not available or misspelled.`, "<br>"]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        writeLines(["Missing language argument. Usage: changelanguage [en/fr]", "<br>"]);
      }
      break;

    case 'whoami':
      if(bareMode) {
        writeLines([`I am still searching about who am i..`, "<br>"])
        break;
      }
      writeLines(createWhoami());
      break;
    case 'about':
      if(bareMode) {
        writeLines(["Nothing to see here.", "<br>"])
        break;
      }
      writeLines(ABOUT);
      break;
    case 'projects':
      if(bareMode) {
        writeLines(["I don't want you to break the other projects.", "<br>"])
        break;
      }
      writeLines(PROJECTS);
      break;
    case 'repo':
      writeLines(["Redirecting to github.com...", "<br>"]);
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.open(REPO_LINK, '_blank');
      }, 500);
      break;
    case 'linkedin':
      //add stuff here
      break;
    case 'github':
      //add stuff here
      break;
    case 'email':
      //add stuff here
      break;
    case 'rm -rf':
      if (bareMode) {
        writeLines(["don't try again.", "<br>"])
        break;
      }

      if (isSudo) {
        writeLines(["Usage: <span class='command'>'rm -rf &lt;dir&gt;'</span>", "<br>"]);
      } else {
        writeLines(["Permission not granted.", "<br>"])
      }
        break;
    case 'sudo':
      if(bareMode) {
        writeLines(["no.", "<br>"])
        break;
      }
      if(!PASSWORD) return
      isPasswordInput = true;
      USERINPUT.disabled = true;

      if(INPUT_HIDDEN) INPUT_HIDDEN.style.display = "none";
      PASSWORD.style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(() => {
        PASSWORD_INPUT.focus();
      }, 100);

      break;
    case 'ls':
      if(bareMode) {
        writeLines(["", "<br>"])
        break;
      }

      if (isSudo) {
        writeLines(["src", "<br>"]);
      } else {
        writeLines(["Permission not granted.", "<br>"]);
      }
      break;
    default:
      if(bareMode) {
        writeLines(["type 'help'", "<br>"])
        break;
      }

      writeLines(DEFAULT);
      break;
  }  
}

function writeLines(message : string[]) {
  message.forEach((item, idx) => {
    displayText(item, idx);
  });
}

function displayText(item : string, idx : number) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(!mutWriteLines) return
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = item;
    mutWriteLines.parentNode!.insertBefore(p, mutWriteLines);
    scrollToBottom();
  }, 40 * idx);
}

function revertPasswordChanges() {
    if (!INPUT_HIDDEN || !PASSWORD) return
    PASSWORD_INPUT.value = "";
    USERINPUT.disabled = false;
    INPUT_HIDDEN.style.display = "block";
    PASSWORD.style.display = "none";
    isPasswordInput = false;

    setTimeout(() => {
      USERINPUT.focus();
    }, 200)
}

function passwordHandler() {
  if (passwordCounter === 2) {
    if (!INPUT_HIDDEN || !mutWriteLines || !PASSWORD) return
    writeLines(["<br>", "INCORRECT PASSWORD.", "PERMISSION NOT GRANTED.", "<br>"])
    revertPasswordChanges();
    passwordCounter = 0;
    return
  }

  if (PASSWORD_INPUT.value === SUDO_PASSWORD) {
    if (!mutWriteLines || !mutWriteLines.parentNode) return
    writeLines(["<br>", "PERMISSION GRANTED.", "Try <span class='command'>'rm -rf'</span>", "<br>"])
    revertPasswordChanges();
    isSudo = true;
    return
  } else {
    PASSWORD_INPUT.value = "";
    passwordCounter++;
  }
}

function easterEggStyles() {   
  const bars = document.getElementById("bars");
  const body = document.body;
  const main = document.getElementById("main");
  const span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

  if (!bars) return
  bars.innerHTML = "";
  bars.remove()

  if (main) main.style.border = "none";

  body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  body.style.fontFamily = "VT323, monospace";
  body.style.fontSize = "20px";
  body.style.color = "white";

  for (let i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
    span[i].style.color = "white";
  }

  USERINPUT.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  USERINPUT.style.color = "white";
  USERINPUT.style.fontFamily = "VT323, monospace";
  USERINPUT.style.fontSize = "20px";
  if (PROMPT) PROMPT.style.color = "white";

}

const initEventListeners = () => {
  if(HOST) {
    HOST.innerText= command.hostname;
  }

  if(USER) {
    USER.innerText = command.username;
  }

  if(PRE_HOST) {
    PRE_HOST.innerText= command.hostname;
  }

  if(PRE_USER) {
    PRE_USER.innerText = command.username;
  } 

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    writeLines(BANNER);
  });
  
  USERINPUT.addEventListener('keypress', userInputHandler);
  USERINPUT.addEventListener('keydown', userInputHandler);
  PASSWORD_INPUT.addEventListener('keypress', userInputHandler);

  window.addEventListener('click', () => {
    USERINPUT.focus();
  });

  console.log(`%cPassword: ${command.password}`, "color: red; font-size: 20px;");
}

initEventListeners();
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/css-reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-png" href="/res/logo.png" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d5effce557.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>WebShell</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main">
    <div id="bars">
      <div id="bar-1">WebShell.x64_x86</div>
      <div id="bar-2"></div>
      <div id="bar-3"></div>
      <div id="bar-4"></div>
      <div id="bar-5"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="terminal">
      <div>
        <span id="prompt"><span id="pre-user"></span>@<span id="pre-host"></span>:$ ~ </span>
      </div>
      <!-- command output will be inserted before #write-lines-->
      <a id="write-lines"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="input-line">
      <div>
        <p id="password-input" style="display: none;">Password: <input id="password-field" autocomplete="off"
            type="password" /></p>
        <p id="input-hidden">
          <span id="prompt"><span id="user"></span>@<span id="host"></span>:$ ~
          </span>
          <input id="user-input" type="text" enterkeyhint="Enter" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="none"
            autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

<script type="module" src="./src/styles.ts"></script>
<script type="module" src="./src/main.ts"></script>

</html>
```

src/language/en.json

```
{
  "bannergreetings": "Welcome to CatalOS CLI v0.1",

  "languagecommand": "language",
  "languagecommanddesc": "Change the actual system language.",

  "changedlanguage": "Language changed to english successfully.",

  "greeting": "Hello",
  "message": "Welcome to our website"
}
```

src/language/fr.json

```
{
  "bannergreetings": "Bienvenue sur CatalOS CLI v0.1",

  "languagecommand": "language",
  "languagecommanddesc": "Changer le language du système actuel.",

  "changedlanguage": "Langue changer en français avec succès.",

  "greeting": "Bonjour",
  "message": "Bienvenue sur notre site"
}
```

I tryied to modify the way i call banner i tryied to modify the code of the banner itself and tryied to modify tsconfig parameter but none of these thing worked. As i understand my "components" inside commands folder are all static by the "vite optimization" but i can't figure out what the issue and how to solve it. When i change language in the main.ts all the traducted text are working but the traducted text inside banner or help that in the command folder are not traducted and still in english.